# Render any Literate Haskell to PDF, HTML, or similar

Tags: haskell, latex

How to I convert a Literate Haskell file to something easier on the eyes?  Here's what happens when I try to do the obvious thing:

```
$ latex Check.lhs
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./Check.lhs
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Environment code undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{code}
```

I'm not familiar with the usual commands for processing tex files.  What's a simple, no-nonsense way I can use to convert just about any `.lhs` file to e.g. PDF or HTML?

Answer (score 12):

In this space you can use lhs2TeX, which has quite a few options but can give quite nice results on formatting. It has pretty extensive documentation, which you can find on the [homepage](http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/).

An example of usage (directly from the manual) would be

```
\documentclass{article}
%include polycode.fmt
\begin{document}
This is the famous ‘‘Hello world’’ example,
written in Haskell:
\begin{code}
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

The `\documentclass{article}`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are all TeX commands to indicate what kind of document you want, and where it starts/ends.

The `%include polycode.fmt` is actually a comment in TeX, but will indicate to lhs2TeX what format to use when processing the `.lhs` file.

You can compile the example with

```
$ lhs2TeX -o HelloWorld.tex HelloWorld.lhs
$ pdflatex HelloWorld.tex
```

For HTML you can also try [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html), which can give you all sorts of output formats (pdf, html, rtf, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You want to preprocess your literate files with [lhs2tex](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lhs2tex).